# Send params to Joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I write custom module, for example, when module called with parametr 1, module return 1, when called with 2, return 2 e.t.c.

But I cant find any documentation, how to send parametrs from page to module. Its how I call module now:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );                              
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('NAME_OF_CUSTOM_POSITION');
$count_array = count($modules);
if ($count_array >0)
    {
    $attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $modules[0], $attribs );
    }                            
?>
```

But I don't know how to send params nor how to recieve them in my module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used below code in one of my custom component.And it worked for me.

```
$document   = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');        
$params   = array('style'=>'xhtml');        
$contents   = '';
foreach (JModuleHelper::getModules('NAME_OF_CUSTOM_POSITION') as $mod)  {   
    $registry   = new JRegistry();
    $registry->loadString($mod->params);
    $registry->set('paramname','paramvalue');   
    $mod->params = (string)$registry;
    $contents .= $renderer->render($mod, $params);
}
echo $contents;
```

Comment: and how I get this params in my module? Or should I just use $params for params in my mod_module.php?

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: yes, you can get it using $params variable.